# How to show only one object if there are few in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to use a list but still it shows all the values.

```
allexpelorer1    = Destination.objects.filter(destination = pk).order_by('-pk')
allexpelorer = []
for checkhu in allexpelorer1:
    if Destination.objects.filter(destination = pk, user_pk = checkhu.user_pk) not in allexpelorer:
        allexpelorer.append(checkhu)
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Show only the first filtered Destination?

Comment: example: There is a travel blog and people can write about their experience that what countries they have travel, They can write few times for each country but in the country profile I want to show who wrote experience for that country. I can show who wrote but if one user write few times it shows few times but I want show only one time(I mean the user profile)

Answer (score 0):

From your question, what I have understood:

**Tourists** write about the **experience** of the **countries** that they have visited. So, obviously, tourists can write **multiple reviews**.

The table structure should look like the following:

**CustomerReviewsTable / CountryProfileTable**

[image]

Tourist_One has written 3 times for both countries.

Tourist_Two has written 1 time for each country.

Here is the query you should follow:

```
country = 1 # Denmark
max_ids = Yourmodel.objects.filter(country = country).values('tourist','country').annotate(max_id=Max('pk')).values('max_id')
```

Then query again

```
result = Yourmodel.objects.filter(id__in = max_ids)
```

**The above result Queryset will return your expected result.**

-When Country 1 passed:

Denmark | Review1 | Tourist_One

Denmark | Review4 | Tourist_Two

-When Country 2 passed:

Italy  | Review3  | Tourist_One

Italy  | Review5  | Tourist_Two

**Now, this will not bring any duplicate comments/reviews.**

Comment: @RaminZamani, can you let me know what problem you are facing currently? I have tested locally with the above models. Worked for me. 
If you elaborate on your problem, then perhaps I can guide you through it.